# How does the use of linearity of normal distribution help determine variance of simple linear regression parameters?

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

On page 401 of the famous Walpole textbook on statistics (*Probabilities and Statistics for Engineers & Scientists*), I stumbled upon this reasoning for the variance formula of the $\beta_1$ estimator (regression slope coefficient). The mentioned Theorem 7.11 says about stability of the normal distribution.

My question is how does the stability help us conclude anything about variance of $B_1$?

Also, why does the $c_i$ expression follow the normal distribution?

[image]

Comment: I suppose they assume that $Y_i$ follows a normal distribution. And the sum shows that the estimator is a linear combination of normal random variables, which is also normal

Comment: To be perfectly clear, we are all assuming that what these authors mean by "stability" is that a linear combination of independent Normal variables has a Normal distribution.  This is the standard meaning of a ["stable" family of distributions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book but it is clear the authors are talking about the (unbiased) estimator of $\beta_1$ in the conditional normal regression model.

Observe that $Y_i$'s are independent normal rvs, namely $Y_i\sim \mathcal N(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i,\sigma^2).$

The estimator of $\beta_1$ is a linear function of $Y_i$'s that is, $$\hat \beta_1 =\sum_{i=1}^n c_i Y_i.\tag 1\label 1$$

Now, it is known that if $Z_i\sim\mathcal N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) $ are independent rvs, then $$ \sum_{i=1}^n (a_iZ_i+b_i) \sim\mathcal N\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i\mu_i+b_i) ,\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\sigma_i^2\right).\tag 2\label 2$$

Applying $\eqref 2$ on $\eqref 1$ yields the desired result.

Comment: aah, so the value of c_i is not particularly important?
If I understood this correctly, we only need the c_i as the coefficient in the linear combination term which to make conclusions about the normality of the sum of those linear combinations (β1) - your (2) equation?

Comment: Correct that is.